# Is there a new way to shuffle an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, shuffle

I am relatively new to coding (second semester of C++) and am working on a project where I need to shuffle a string array. I did a similar program in the past using random_shuffle() but have discovered that it has since been deprecated. Are there any other ways I can shuffle an array?

I'm using Xcode BTW, in case that needs to be stated.

Any help is greatly appreciated! This is my first post of many, I'm sure.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle the (3) one is not deprecated

Comment: Use  std::shuffle()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::random_shuffle` was deprecated due to its use of the default psuedo random generator, because it was terrible. Now, [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) lets you use c++11's awesome new random device mechanic. You can see that in the overload:

```
template< class RandomIt, class URBG >
void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URBG&& g );
```

Where `URGB` is the randomizer that you want it to use. So now you can just call it like:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
std::shuffle(std::begin(my_array), std::end(my_array), g);
```

And it will be faster and more random then ever.

Comment: Fantastic! Got it working great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SeanVanderaa, feel free to mark the answer as correct.